# How can i add a css rule to a div after specific period of time, set a delay and then add one more css rule, using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

In the "hero" div below i want to add the css rule `left:40px`, set 2 seconds of delay and after the delay add the css rule `left:-100%`.

EDIT: to make the question more clear.

STEP **1**.After 1 second div appear on the screen
STEP **2**.Add a delay of 2 seconds
STEP **3**.Add a new css rule as i described above.

Here is my code

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.hero').css('left', '40px');
}, 1000);
```

```css
.hero {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 1.50);
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki please read my question carefully. I also want to set a delay of 2 seconds and after that delay to add a new css rule.

Comment: Your two css rules are identical. Setting the css to `left:40px` then later setting it to `left:40px`doesnt actually change anything

Comment: No need to be rude,  just add another settimeout within your function.

Comment: @rich sorry my mistake the second rule must be `left:-100%` i edited it

Comment: @BobtheMagicMoose i apologize if i somehow seemed to be rude. I really wasn't intend to.

Comment: I think you just want **Hello world** to display for 2 seconds and again hide. ?

Comment: @KamalaHB yes but i want to do that using css rules and not just show/hide because of the transitions i need to use there.

Comment: @Designer please read the [SO code of conduct](https://stackoverflow.com/conduct) asking if people read your question and telling them to read it carefully is quite unfriendly and a little rude and could be classed as a subtle put-downs

Comment: @Designer Check my post. It will completely hide.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could nest two `setTimeout`, the second one will start counting when the first is fired, like:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hero').css('left', '40px');

    setTimeout(function() {
        $('.hero').css('left', '-100%');
    }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

You could also use another outside `setTimeout` that will be fire after`3` second like :

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hero').css('left', '40px');
}, 1000);

setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hero').css('left', '-100%');
}, 3000);
```

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.hero').css('left', '40px');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hero').css('left', '-100%');
  }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.hero {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 1.50);
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are willing to dive a little deeper, a promise-based system is very useful because you will not end up nesting multiple `setTimeout` inside each other.

1. Create a `sleep` function, and all it does is that it has `window.setTimeout()` that receives a duration as an argument
2. Use `async`/`await` regime, so that you simply `await` the sleep function before calling the next step:

```js
function sleep(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

async function animateHero() {
  await sleep(1000);
  $('.hero').css('left', '40px');
  await sleep(2000);
  $('.hero').css('left', '-100%');
}

animateHero();
```

```css
.hero {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 1.50);
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Comment: Do we need really a `Promise` in this case ?

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki If you don't want to end up nesting multiple `setTimeout`s within each other, this is the way to go. Then you can daisy chain as many queued animations you want without any problem. A promise is needed because `window.setTimeout` does not natively return a promise (yet).

Comment: You could simply add one after another without if you don't want to nest them.

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki You can, but that means you have to manually recompute all the timeout durations in your code when one step changes. Imagine you have 5 steps, and they have to be invoked after 1s, 2s, 3s, 4s and 5s from the previous sequence .That means the cumulative timeouts will have to be 1000, 3000, 6000, 10000, and 15000ms. That makes code maintenance extremely difficult.

Comment: 1s,3s,6s,10s,15s I don't find it (_extremely difficult._) the opposite it will show you the real time when the settimeout will be reached...

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki When do you ever really need to know the real time? Chances are no. If you need to know when the animation ends, simply check for the resolution of the `Promise` returned by the async `animateHero` function ;) Let's say you want to change the second step to wait 20s instead: that means you will have to manually recalculate all the setTimeout durations for *all subsequent steps*. I can understand tho if you don't like a promise-based system: a lot of people are not used to it yet, despite it being really powerful.

Comment: _When do you ever really need to know the real time? Chances are no_ That may in your point of view and I respect it but don't judge on mine... I love Promise and use it, I just see that it's not the perfect case for it.. Happy coding

Comment: @ZakariaAcharki Dude stop being so combative, I didn't trumpet my answer as better, but it is definitely more readable and maintainable. To each his own :)

Comment: We're talking about the concept not the answers... I don't see something combative in my comments, just saying my point of view... ;)

Answer (score 0):

```js
setTimeout(function() {
  $('.hero').css('left', '40px');

  setTimeout(function() {
    $('.hero').css('left', '-100%');
  }, 2000);
}, 1000);
```

```css
.hero {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 1.50);
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hero">HELLO WORLD</div>
```

Comment: Why are you using `140%`?

Comment: If you run my code and check. You can see that it will hide completely after 2 seconds

Answer (score 0):

That is a great answer from @Terry..... here is his answer without the jquery.... IMO this is the best way.

```js
function sleep(duration) {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    window.setTimeout(resolve, duration);
  });
}

async function animateHero() {
  var target = document.getElementById('target');
  await sleep(1000);
  target.style.left = '40px';
  await sleep(2000);
  target.style.color = 'red';
}

animateHero();
```

```css
.hero {
  background: #eee;
  padding: 10px;
  position: fixed;
  left: -100%;
  transition-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.8, 0.5, 0.8, 1.50);
  transition-duration: 0.8s;
}
```

```html
<div id='target' class="hero">HELLO WORLD</div>
```